# At what point do mySQL indexs start to matter with simple selects?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a table which is growing slowly,  call `people`
currently there are 50,000 records and it gains about 5000 a month.

It was written by someone (not me!)
who didn't add any indexes,
and there are numerous queries that use non-pk where clauses.

For example:

```
select * from people where email = 'person@gmail.com';
```

According to the mysql command line client, this executes in "0" time ...

```
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also tried, in an attempt to make a slower query:

```
# attempt!
select * from people where email like 'Name%';

# result
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My understanding is a query like this does a full table scan.
So if a full table scan of 50,000 rows takes less then 1/100th of a second,
at what point does it actually get slower?

Comment: Are you sure there is no index on email column?

Comment: Why not go to a development copy of the database, add 100000 rows to the table, and try it again? Then add 200000?

Comment: @all this question is not considering as real question until OP update with the table schema and execution plan results

Comment: @ajreal. Its not about a particular table. If you were to actually read the question instead of making mostly worthless edits, you'd understand that.

Comment: @Will how to convincing when you not even include execution plan? forget to add, there is something called `query cache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 50,000 records it *probably* makes sense to create an index to help with queries (or possibly more than one index depending on the queries and how often they are run).  And with only 5,000 records being added each month, the maintenance of the index (assuming not a lot of other updates) shouldn't be very costly.

I do not know how accurate the timer is for those results but it seems within the realm of possibility for a full table scan to occur in less than 1/100 of a second (depending on how aggressive the caching is and how big the physical record size is).  I just now ran a query on my own development PC (with a completely different database engine) that did a full table scan of 40,000 records in .013 seconds. And my dev PC isn't anything special.

(I didn't have a 50,000 record table handy in a MySQL database, but I did have the 40,000 record one immediately available for a different database.  So the comparison may not be exactly comparable, but it probably isn't completely out to lunch.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a lot of performance degradation when you start joining your tables and doing more complex queries than select *.  Or once your table starts getting a bit bigger (performance also depends on your hardware, so it's hard to say when you're going to need to add indexes).

Indexes are really easy to add though, to add an index on the email column, you'd just execute:

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD INDEX (email);
```

Comment: Yes, they are easy to add, but the speed of the table without them had me wondering about the inner workings. At what point are they helpful, in what conditions, etc. I was surprised to find non-indexed queries to be so fast.

Comment: 50k records isn't that many records for many machines, try self joining a few times on `name`, you'll see the performance drop pretty quickly.